# CSRF for internal $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] form

Tags: php, forms, csrf, csrf-protection

Trying to implement CSRF token for the first time ever ...

I have an internal `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]` form ...

Most of the stuff online talks about having it done via `_$POST` php form ...

So ... after reading all that, I've reasoned that since I have it as in internal part, that I should set the token there ...

So this is what I did ... but clearly I'm misunderstanding something here because it's not working ... not just misunderstanding ... I'm also not sure what I'm supposed to do ... so ... if you could explain what I'm supposed to do so I can set it correctly ... I would really appreciate it

```
<?php
session_start(); //allows use of session variables

  $token = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
  $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
  $_SESSION['token_time'] = time();


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

   if (empty($_POST["first-name"])) {
     $firstNameErr = "First name is required";
   } else {
     $first_name = test_input($_POST["first-name"]);
   }

    if (empty($_POST["last-name"])) {
     $lastNameErr = "Last name is required";
   } else {
     $last_name = test_input($_POST["last-name"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
     $emailErr = "Email is required";
   } else {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
     $messageErr = "Message is required";
   } else {
     $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
   }


   if(isset($first_name) && isset($last_name) && isset($email) && isset($message) && isset($token))
   {
     $_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;
     $_SESSION['last_name'] = $last_name;
     $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
     $_SESSION['message'] = $message;
     $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
     header("Location: SessionsCRSF.php");
   }
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>
```

On the same page is the form (placing a snippet, but you get the idea):

```
<form class="ui form"  method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />

  <div class="field">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input name="first-name" id="first-name" placeholder="First Name" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($first_name)) { echo $first_name; }?>">
     <?php if(isset($firstNameErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $firstNameErr . '</span>'); ?>
  </div>

(...)

</form>
```

But I don't know how to test it via `SessionsCRSF.php` form that you see listed in the header ...

Here's the snippet of `SessionsCRSF.php` form since the rest is just PHPMailer stuff:

```
<?php

session_start();

    if ($_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['token'])
    {
      die('working, yay?'); 
    }


$first_name = $_SESSION['first-name'];
$last_name = $_SESSION['last-name'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$message = nl2br($_SESSION['message']);

require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
```

**EDITED**

Ok, so .. this is what I have so far that works:

```
<?php
session_start(); //allows use of session variables

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && $_SESSION['token'] == $_POST['token'] && !empty($_SESSION['token'])) {

   if (empty($_POST["first-name"])) {
     $firstNameErr = "First name is required";
   } else {
     $first_name = test_input($_POST["first-name"]);
   }

    if (empty($_POST["last-name"])) {
     $lastNameErr = "Last name is required";
   } else {
     $last_name = test_input($_POST["last-name"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
     $emailErr = "Email is required";
   } else {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
     $messageErr = "Message is required";
   } else {
     $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
   }

   if(isset($first_name) && isset($last_name) && isset($email) && isset($message))
   {
     $_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;
     $_SESSION['last_name'] = $last_name;
     $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
     $_SESSION['message'] = $message;
     header("Location: contact9SessionsCRSF2.php");
     exit; 
   }
}
else {
  $token = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
  $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
  $_SESSION['token_time'] = time();
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>
```

Comment: You're not posting to SessionsCRSF.php so `if ($_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['token'])` cannot possibly work since `$_POST['token']` variable doesn't exist. At the very least, this will make your test fail.

Comment: @JoeRose, I thought it was sorta being posted via the function above `test_input` ... and then the header takes it to `SessionCRSF.php`? I don't know ... how do I make it work? I mean, it's not a `$_POST`, right? But more of a `$_SESSION`? So, do I write this instead `if ($_SESSION['token'] == $_SESSION['token'])`? If you could explain how I could make this work, I would really appreciate it! =)

Comment: I think a better way to do it is to create a class that handles the CRSF and then pass the posted token and the session token to the class, then gets back whether it is valid or not, and then your current page can execute some code based on this response (like displaying the page again with an error message for the user). If you don't want to write a class, you might find a good one at [link](http://www.phpclasses.org) that you can just add in to your application (I saw a bunch of results when searching for CSRF).

Comment: @JoeRose, well, I thought it was relatively simple to implement a CSRF token based on this article: http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries ... and if I can do it that way, I'd like to. I don't really want to write a class, nor rely on an outside script because this is for commercial purposes, and I'm expected to maintain it, so I'd like to understand what I'm doing here if that's possible. Shrugs.

Comment: in that case, why not just post to the current page, verify the token on the current page (which has access to the `$token` and `$_POST['token']` variables, check for matching, and then act based on that, instead of using an outside page. You can then echo the form data from the session into the form fields if the token was incorrect and the page needs to be redisplayed (make sure to use headers to redirect to the same page to eliminate the possibility of a form resubmission), or if the token was correct, you can do your PHPMailer code and then redirect to a success page.

Comment: Hi @user27307254534534534543675765 , yes, my "Solution" part was correct but was then superceded by the code in my codeblock, I should have made that more obvious. your "Edited" code block should work now - as long as your form has the `<input name='token' ... >` part.

Comment: @Martin, it does! `  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />`. So you're saying that my edited post is correct for functional form, yes?

Comment: yes! I mean, try it and see!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your page, which contains your `$_SESSION` value, and you have your INPUT value in the hidden field in your HTML form which are the same value.

```
Page 1:
[SESSION] ... [INPUT]
```

You then submit the form to the destination address, here Page 2, and then check that your submitted hidden field value is equal to the `$_SESSION` value, which is not passed by the input form field.

This input value is found from the `$_POST` array.

```
Page 2: 
[SESSION] ... [POST]
```

Specifically to your problem, your submitting your form to the `PHP_SELF` page (generally `PHP_SELF` is a bad variable to use and it is not encouraged), which is the same page. BUT, your checking of the data is done on the `sessionCRSF.php` page, so what you should do is update your form to put:

```
<form action='sessionCRSF.php' ... >
```

And then at the top of that page your check of the token value should succeed.

---

You seem to show some confusion as to SERVER request methods, there are GET/POST/PUT and other ones and if you have an

> I have an internal $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] form

what actually is this? If it's a form then it's a GET/POST method, and that's not internal, as far as I am aware - even if it's on the same server it's from one page to another, so the concepts above apply.

## Solution

From discussion and clarification I can now see the solution:

In the `If` statements that handle the form submission, you do not have any handling of the token posted value, `$_POST['token']`. So you need to add a statement to handle that, in its simplest form, at the point of the code where you set the values for the `$_SESSION` form data, add a line:

```
$_SESSION['posted_token'] = $_POST['token'];
```

That's all you need, then in the `sessionCRSF.php` you compare these two values so you then have:

```
 if ($_SESSION['posted_token'] == $_SESSION['token'])
    {
      die('working, yay?'); 
    }
```

(You had me confused earlier with reference to "internal" forms etc.!)

## Edit :

You need to set the original `$_SESSION['token']` when the form is generated, *NOT* when the form is submitted, your code currently creates the `$_SESSION['token']` value on every iteration, and because the page self refers it means that the token values -- being random -- will never ever be the same. You need to set

```
if (form submitted){
   save submitted POSTED token
}
else{
    /// form not submitted
    generate a token and save to session
}
```

Do not do both of these things on the same iteration!!

## Code

Because sometimes it's easier just to see it....

*Code has been updated to compare the tokens on POST submission and therefore bypassing the entire need for sending the data to another page to be compared.*

```
<?php
session_start(); //allows use of session variables


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && 
$_SESSION['token'] == $_POST['token'] && !empty($_SESSION['token'])) {

   if (empty($_POST["first-name"])) {
     $firstNameErr = "First name is required";
   } else {
     $first_name = test_input($_POST["first-name"]);
   }

    ...etc...

   if(isset($first_name) && isset($last_name) && isset($email) && isset($message))
   {
     $_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;
     $_SESSION['last_name'] = $last_name;
     $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
     $_SESSION['message'] = $message;

     header("Location: SessionsCRSF.php");
     exit; //ALWAYS end execution after sending location headers. 
   }
}
else {
  $token = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
  $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
  $_SESSION['token_time'] = time();
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks for responding and for explaining. I get Page 1, and Page 2 stuff that you explained. The only reason why I can't update the `<form action = 'sessionCRSF.php ... >` is because I'm self-submitting it for validation, and then using the header to carry over the variables to the `sessionsCRSF.php` page. Hence my confusion in trying to figure out how to carry over hidden CSRF token over to sessionCRSF.php page so it can be checked. If I explained my confusion badly, please let me know. It's the reason why I posted both the top and second part of code.

Comment: @user27307254534534534543675765 I don;t understand the logic of your processes, you have a form on a page, and this form submits to another page, which is then carried over to the `sessionCRSF.php` page? That sounds confused. The form can be submitted to another page and that page than then execute and then forward to a final resting page, is that possible?

Comment: If your form submission and activation is "internal" then you don't need to worry about CSRF because others won't be able to access and submit the data to carry out the forgery.

Comment: no, the form submits to itself, hence this line: `action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">`. First part of code, and second part of code are on the same page. Then I try to carry it over to `sessionCRSF.php` page. I thought that even though I'm using `action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">`, I still had to worry about CSRF?

Comment: forms self submitting is a bad idea as if someone refreshes the page then the form will submit again, and repetition will occur. Form should submit to an external page when then can return to the form page once the submission has been dealt with. Can you describe what "carry over" actually is, what method actually passes the focus to the `sessionCRSF.php` page; Is it a `header` or an `include`, etc?

Comment: @user27307254534534534543675765 the key to this issue the more I think about it, is the way the information and focus is transfered from the form submission page to the `sessionCRSF.php` page, if each page has `session_Start();` and the final page takes the `POST`ed  value as a PHP variable `$posted_token` then the way you have it should work....

Comment: @Martin - Self-submit is fine as long as headers are used to redirect to the same page, and the values can be carried over via the `session` variable.

Comment: @Martin, please look first part of the code, and scroll down. Look at the code above the `test_function`, and you would see that it's relying on the header to carry it over to `sessionCRSF.php` page assuming it's been set.

Comment: @JoeRose I was a tiny bit excessive in that statement but self submitting forms need an excess of careful checking work to stop them repeating form inputs, I've seen a few (2) decent examples of this but overall, it's far easier to submit to an outside page and then return once form data is taken care of....

Comment: @user27307254534534534543675765 I have posted the solution on my answer, see my edit above :) .

Comment: @user27307254534534534543675765 also added an edit and a code block :)

Comment: @Martin, hey, thank you for your solution, and edits, and code block! =) Um, to clarify, you're saying that I don't need my earlier generated token above the first name thing? Because what I see in your code block, it seems to be generated in the else block, right? Please excuse my confusion.

Comment: I updated my code to put the token checking in the PHP before the `sessionCRSF.php` is even called. This is what the token is intended for, so that if the token that's passed to the script (POST) doesn't match the one the script has (SESSION), it carries on as if nothing has been submitted. nothing needs to be passed to the sessionCRSF.php page :-)

Comment: @Martin, ok, I've copied your code almost verbatim, the only thing I didn't copy over is this line: `$_SESSION['posted_token'] = $_POST['token'];`. It wouldn't work unless I changed it to this: `$_SESSION['token'] = $_POST['token'];` Is that ok?

Comment: @Martin, it wasn't going to work either way because there's no other reference to `posted_token` aside from that line ... hence me changing it to just `token` ...

Comment: @user27307254534534534543675765 Please check my updated code, there's no need for the `posted_token` value, but the concept is that if the check was to happen in another page, that *BOTH* the posted and the session values would need to be passed across, so they'd both be passed as different `$_SESSION` variables. Please check my code now, that's my final version :D

Comment: and in my answer above the **edit** part, that's where the defunct `$_SESSION['posted_token']` would have been used, in the `sessionCRSF.php` page. But that's redundant now as the check can be done at the top of the form page.

Comment: @user27307254534534534543675765 ok that's my final edit. All done now. Promise! :-) the code block at the bottom of my answer is all you need on your form to take the hidden posted value with the name `token` and compare it to your session value to check that the form submission is genuine.

Comment: @Martin, hey, thank you so much for taking the time to read, figure out my post, and help me out on this. I appreciate it so much! I still have a couple more questions, but will put it out on other questions. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Martin, just one quick question if you don't mind, otherwise I'll post it as separate question but you know the context and all .... (don't worry, I'll upvote your answer so you'll get extra points) ... for the `sessionsCRSF.php` page, it should be this: `if ($_SESSION['token'] == $_SESSION['token']){ 
  die('Yay, working?');
}` yes?

Comment: ah no worries, it's nice to solve things. Does the form submission work as intended now?

Comment: If you see the **Solution** part of my answer, there are ***two*** values in the SESSION, the session is an array and there are two values, one is the original `token` and the other is the form posted value which I just set as `posted_token` and so these two values need to be the same to show that the form is genuine. Hence these values needs to be saved with different names in the `$_SESSION` array.

Comment: If you use my code above, you do not need the `sessionCSRF.php` at all, as that part of the security has been done already in the `If` statement in my codeblock.

Comment: (my above comment is assuming that the file `sessionCRSF.php` is solely intended for checking form submission tokens, due to its name. @user27307254534534534543675765 )

Comment: @Martin, please excuse me ... seems I'm having a brain fart somewhere ... (when am I not really) ... having a bit of difficulty grasping this apparently ... give me a 15ish minutes and I'll edit in my post what I think I'm supposed to do, and if it works, and can you let know if I got it correctly?

Comment: @Martin, ok, so, have posted in the edited part of my post based on your solution. Did I configure it correctly?